Trying to install and configure correctly Xorg and the nvidia drivers in/on Open Indiana virtualized with bhyve on FreeBSD 14.1
I've just virtualized Open Indiana in bhyve (FreeBSD hypervisor),using the following parameters :
bhyve-win -S -c sockets=2,cores=2,threads=2 -m 4G -w -H -A \
-s 0,hostbridge \
-s 1,ahci-hd,/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Open-Indiana/efi/Minimal/openindiana-1.img \
-s 8:0,passthru,2/0/0 \
-s 8:1,passthru,2/0/1 \
-s 8:2,passthru,2/0/2 \
-s 8:3,passthru,2/0/3 \
-s 13,virtio-net,tap5 \
-s 29,fbuf,tcp=0.0.0.0:5905,w=1600,h=950,wait \
-s 31,lpc \
-l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_UEFI_CODE.fd \
vm0:5 < /dev/null & sleep 2 && vncviewer 0:5 &

You can see that between the bhyve parameters I'm passing thru the 4 slots of my GPU,nvidia geforce 2080 ti,that are the following ones :
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 
[GeForce RTX 2080 Ti]
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 High Definition 
Audio Controller
02:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB 3.1 Host 
Controller
02:00.3 Serial bus controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 USB 
Type-C UCSI Controller

What I did within the OI vm ? I've installed xorg ; mate and the nvidia drivers and then I've issued the command : "startx". Well,I expected that my external monitor (attached to the HDMI port of the GPU Geforce 2080 ti was able to turn on,but this didn't happen. Instead,I see some kind of error that prevents it from doing it :
https://ibb.co/YbMW5F6
This is the xorg.conf file that I've created :
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "nvidia
        BusID       "PCI:0:0:8"
EndSection

I hope that the address 0:0:8 is correct,according with the PCI address assigned to the GPU :
https://ibb.co/KqFqfRS
I don't understand why it wants to use the device 0:0:29 instead of the 0:0:8 when I have used the 0:0:8 and the 0:0:29 can't be used because it is the framebuffer....
